mysql query to summarize data
I am trying to summarize some data from two data sources. The tables are following
Table t1



auto_id
unique_column
value




1
d1
10


2
d2
5


3
d3
15



Table t2



auto_id
unique_column
value




null
d3
5


null
d4
6



Expected data in t1 after query:



auto_id
unique_column
value




1
d1
10


2
d2
5


3
d3
20


4
d4
6



To solve this I was planning to do the following query
REPLACE INTO t1
SELECT auto_id, unique_column, SUM(value) value FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM t1
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT * FROM t2
) GROUP BY unique_column; 

Issue with this query
SELECT auto_id, unique_column, SUM(value) value FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM t1
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT * FROM t2
) GROUP BY unique_column; 

The above query will give us



auto_id
unique_column
value




1
d1
10


2
d2
5


3
d3
20


NULL
d4
6



Which is okay. In the insert query we will get the following result:



auto_id
unique_column
value




1
d1
10


2
d2
5


3
d3
20


4
d4
6



But the following query
SELECT auto_id, unique_column, SUM(value) value FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM t2
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT * FROM t1
) GROUP BY unique_column; 

will give us



auto_id
unique_column
value




1
d1
10


2
d2
5


NULL
d3
20


NULL
d4
6



So, Insert query will product the following unexpected result



auto_id
unique_column
value




1
d1
10


2
d2
5


3
d3
15


4
d3
20


5
d4
6



Alternative thought was, full outer join but mysql decided not to implement this. What other alternative can be done with mysql?

You were close:
REPLACE INTO t1
SELECT MAX(auto_id), unique_column, SUM(value) value FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM t1
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT * FROM t2
) t
GROUP BY unique_column;

MAX(auto_id) will skip NULL fields, which will give us just 3 for 'd3'; for the 'd4' case, auto_id will still be NULL, but (as long as the column is declared as AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL), NULL will be replaced by the next number in the sequence.
EDIT for your edit: as long as you properly aggregate auto_id using MAX (or MIN), the only scenario NULL appears is if you have no prior auto_id; it is not sensitive to ordering.

Now I feel silly!

No need to feel silly; I don't think this is as obvious as it might seem to be in retrospect.
